# xcode error loading png file, unexpected character

Tags: xcode, react-native, react-native-ios

I tried to load two png files, one named **checkbox.png**, another named **checkbox_ok.png**.

for the first time I load **checkbox.png**, it shows error

```
Syntax Error /images/checkbox.png: Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
```

but then this error gone for my second or third time load.

After that I tried to load another file **checkbox_ok.png**. But this time the error happened and never gone.

What can I do to solve this problem?

[Problematic image file here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6OVnMU8m9emRGI5Y0xHODNSNEk/view?usp=sharing)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick solution.
You should restart packager whenever updating(pasting) new images. (`npm restart`)

Comment: thanks. it worked after closing every auto-opened terminal window, and run again!